# The Netherlands Schengen visa

Tags: pakistani-citizens, eu-citizens, application-status, spouses, schengen-visas

I have applied to the Netherlands for a Schengen visa. My husband is a UK national and we are planning a two-week visit to the Netherlands. I attached copies of my marriage certificate, my husband's UK passport, my Pakistani passport, my ticket reservation and hotel booking. My husband doesn't need a visa, and I have applied at VFS Lahore, Pakistan, as the non-EU spouse of an EU/EEA member.

On 25 November, I received an email from Embassy of the Netherlands that they have extended my application time period from 15 days to one month and that I should contact IND (Immigration & Naturalisation Service) with my further inquiries.

Will the IND make its decision in my favour or not? Why are they taking so much time?

Comment: We don't know if your application will be successful or not, there's not enough information to even make a guess.

Comment: @nazia be patient and hope for the best. It is very usual for embassies and consulates like schengen and uk may take extra time  normally 4 to 6 weeks for further verification. Also no one can answer here whether your application would be successful.

Answer (score 4):

Your visa application is not like an ordinary visa application. Your husband as the **right** to travel to the Netherlands, and he has the **right** to take you with him. There are just a few conditions how they can refuse, mostly:

- You did not explain that you will travel *with* your husband.
- They believe that the marriage is not genuine.
- They believe that you, personally, are a threat to public safety or health.

If none of those is the case, just wait a few more days.

Comment: I got refusal on my Netherlands schengen visa application . They refused it on the rule of 2004/38/EC . Even my marriage cerificate is real and all other documents are real.

Comment: So what I should do know ?

Comment: @Nazia, can you scan the refusal notice, blank out any personal information, and add it to your original question? I do not understand if they do not believe your documents or what else might have caused that refusal.